# Key hook for window on Rust

Tags: user-interface, rust, input, keyboard, rust-tokio

Could you please help with event catching problem?
I have a window, and I want to catch keyboard event if window not in focused state now.
For it in overlay constructor I use next:

```
    let (button_sender, button_receiver) = mpsc::channel(10000);
    match keylogger::install_hook(Box::new(move |button| {
        println!("press {}", button);
        let button_sender1 = button_sender.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("tokio::spawn");
            button_sender1.send(button).await.unwrap();
        });
    })) {
        Ok(..) => {
            #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
            println!("Hook installed");
        }
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
        }
    };
```

And after that in event loop I checked when key is pressed:

```
custom_window_frame(ctx, |ui| {
let pressed_button: KeyboardButton = match self.button_receiver.try_recv() {
  Ok(button) => {
    dbg!(button);
    button
}
  Err(_) => KeyboardButton::Undefined,
};
```

After I checking keys in if, something like `if pressed_button == KeyboardButton::F12`
But if my window not focused and I try to use, for example Esc or F12, I see next error:

```
thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\live-translator-rs.exe` (exit code: 0xc000041d)
```

Maybe someone worked with tokio and maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Interesting, that when I try to catch mouse moving event all works fine, when window is focused. But when focus lost, event just stop to do something, without any thread overflowing errors.

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: egui library: https://docs.rs/egui/latest/egui/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)